# why isnt my thread starting?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I'm making a threaded app, and the main class is also the runnable class. for some reason, my thread WILL NOT START. any idea why? updateThread is the culprit...

here is the code:

```
package avtech.software.bitprice.display;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import avtech.software.bitprice.dialogs.*;
import avtech.software.bitprice.listeners.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Display extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    /**
     * variables
     */
    private static final int WIDTH = 200, HEIGHT = 200;
    private static double currentPrice = 0.0;
    private static double pauseLength;
    private static boolean running = false;
    private static String greaterLess = "";
    /**
     * objects
     */
    private static Display d;
    private static Thread updateThread;
    private static JLabel currentPriceLabel = new JLabel("Current Price: $" + currentPrice);
    private static JTextField pullDelayArea = new JTextField("Price Pull Delay In Minutes...");
    private static JTextField priceValueArea = new JTextField("Price You Are Waiting For...");
    private static JButton update = new JButton("UPDATE DATA");

    public Display() {
        running = true; // program is now running
        updateThread = new Thread(d); // create the local thread

        /**
         * create the frame
         */
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("BitPrice");

        /**
         * set bounds of the components
         */
        currentPriceLabel.setBounds(((WIDTH / 2) - (currentPriceLabel.toString().length() / 5)), 5, WIDTH, 50);
        pullDelayArea.setBounds(10, 40, WIDTH - 25, 25);
        priceValueArea.setBounds(10, 70, WIDTH - 25, 25);
        update.setBounds(10, 100, WIDTH - 25, 25);

        /**
         * set up the listeners to the components
         */
        pullDelayArea.addMouseListener(new PullDelayAreaListener(pullDelayArea));
        pullDelayArea.addActionListener(new PullDelayAreaListener(pullDelayArea));
        priceValueArea.addMouseListener(new PriceValueAreaListener(priceValueArea));
        priceValueArea.addActionListener(new PriceValueAreaListener(priceValueArea));
        update.addActionListener(new UpdateButtonListener());

        /**
         * add everything
         */
        add(currentPriceLabel);
        add(pullDelayArea);
        add(priceValueArea);
        add(update);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        requestFocus();

        /**
         * start the update process
         */
        System.out.println("hi");
        updateThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * everything that happens when the thread is updated, including updating
     * the price label, and all that good stuff :)
     */
    public static void update() {
        /**
         * make sure that there is data in the boxes taht is valid
         */
        if (pullDelayArea.getText().equals("Price Pull Delay In Minutes...") || pullDelayArea.getText().equals("")) {
            new MessageDialog(d, "Please enter a valid number into Price Pull Delay.");
        }
        if (priceValueArea.getText().equals("Price You Are Waiting For...") || priceValueArea.getText().equals("")) {
            new MessageDialog(d, "Please enter a valid number into Price Value.");
        }

        // set the new price double from the website

        // update the label
        currentPriceLabel.setText("Current Price: $" + currentPrice);
        currentPriceLabel.setBounds(((WIDTH / 2) - (currentPriceLabel.toString().length() / 5)), 5, WIDTH, 50);
        currentPriceLabel.repaint();

        /**
         * check to see if the current value is what the client is waiting for
         */
        String priceValueString = priceValueArea.getText();
        double priceValue = Double.parseDouble(priceValueString);

    }

    /**
     * this thread is checking the price of the Bitcoin, and will send out the
     * notification if it reaches a certain price
     */
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("started");
        /**
         * initial pause, letting the client get all set up
         */
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            new ErrorDialog(this, "Error delaying the pull request. Please restart client.");
        }
        System.out.println("started");
        while (running) {
            update();

            /**
             * add a pause to not just destroy internet speeds, pause settable
             * through the GUI
             */
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (pauseLength * 1000000)); // 1 million cause
                                                                // its in
                // milliseconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                new ErrorDialog(this, "Error delaying the pull request. Please restart client.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        d = new Display();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: my internet is about to turn off, so responses may be delayed until tomorrow.

Comment: This is a terrible use of statics and it might be biting you in the tail. You're assigning d to a new Display object and then using that same variable inside of the Display constructor? This makes my head spin. You shouldn't be doing this, using an object before its constructed.

Comment: ok, i'm not quite sure what you mean.... lol. also, would that maybe be why my thread isnt starting? cause that is my issue...

Comment: First and foremost -- get rid of **every** static variable that you're using. Every one. Then fix your code so that you don't need static variables.

Comment: Not mention a nice example of how to violate the single thread rules of Swing :P

Comment: What happens when the Display ctor returns?

Comment: If this is an assignment, what are the explicit requirements? I see significant potential problems in your code.

Comment: this is not an assignment. just making a super simple price checking GUI. but, what are these issues?

Comment: You're polling at time intervals rather than responding to user input.

Comment: Basically, you don't need the `Thread` at all for what you are trying to achieve.  Attach appropriate listeners to the fields and update the state as required, rather than nagging me every 2 seconds, over and over and over again...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels there is actually a reason for that... its checking an online site for prices periodically... and Mad, it needs to be able to update automatically, so like every 15 mins or so... so how would i change that?

Comment: Fine, but don't pull in the JTextField text in the poll. Instead have an ActionListener set a String field that is used inside of the thread or timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is that the reference to `d` is not set until the constructor exits, so in your `Display`, you're creating a new thread object and passing the static reference to `d`, which is still presently null at that point. I would remove the `new Thread(d)` line, and the `.start()` line from the constructor, and simply invoke `d.start()` from the main method.

Comment: i see the issue... alright well thank you XD i wouldn't have thought of that.... :) i'll accept this when i can